# Breadth First Search queue

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, breadth-first-search

I am looking at this assignment:

> Consider two vertices a and b that are simultaneously on the FIFO queue at same point during the execution of breadth first search from s in an undirected graph.
>
> **Which of the following is true?**
>
> 1. The number of edges on the shortest path between s and a is atmost one more than the number of edges on the shortest path between s and b.
> 2. The number of edges on the shortest path between s and a is atleast one less than the number of edges on the shortest path between s and b.
> 3. There is a path between a and b.
>
> **Possible answers:**
>
> a) 1 only
>
> b) 1 and 2 only
>
> c) 2 only
>
> d) 1, 2 and 3

I know how to solve it , but just i m having doubt in the meaning of this statement

> ...that are simultaneously on the FIFO queue at same point during the execution of breadth first search...

What is the exact meaning of this?

Comment: Too much homework, eh?

Comment: I assume that it's a typo and is meant to be "that are simultaneously on the FIFO queue at **some** point...".

Comment: @beaker, yes its a typo. it should be "some".

Comment: You shouldn't be asking for answers to your assignments on SO. People (at least me) won't want to answer.

Answer (score 2):

As @beaker already commented, there is a typo in the assignment. The word *same* should be read as *some*:

> Consider two vertices a and b that are simultaneously on the FIFO queue at `some` point during the execution of breadth first search from s in an undirected graph.

By the definition of Breadth-First, the nodes you find in the queue after the n<sup>th</sup> iteration of the search, are *n* steps away from the starting node *s*. When going to the next iteration, this distance is increased by 1, and every node in the queue is taken out of the queue one by one, in order to shift in their neighbors, which are one step further away from *s*. While this process is half-way, there are thus nodes at distance *n* and nodes at distance *n+1* in the queue, until all those of distance *n* have been processed and removed from the queue.

This means that at any given moment, any two nodes that are in the queue, cannot differ more than 1 step in their distance to *s*.

I must say that the phrase *"is at least one less than"* in premise 2 is a bit ambiguous: *"at least"* is to be interpreted mathematically, i.e. as *"not smaller than"*: `dist(a,s)>=dist(b,s)-1`.

Finally, since this is an undirected graph, and we have found a path from *s* to *a* and another path from *s* to *b*, there is also a path from *a* to *b* (via *s*).

This solves the question.

Comment: If <any two nodes cannot differ more than 1 step to s>, then why phrase 2 is correct ? are they conflicted ?

Comment: @JacquelineP, It depends on interpretation. I wrote about this ambiguity in my answer. The phrase could be interpreted as `b - a >= 1` or as `a >= b - 1`. Only the latter is always true.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a graph

During the breadth first traversal of the graph. The status of the queue will be as follows :

S – A → 1 edge

S – B → 1 edge

Difference = 0

S – B → 1 edge

S – C → 2 edge

Difference = 1

Hence, statements S1 and S3 are correct